# Determine the Ramsey number $R(2K_2,3K_2)$

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I am having trouble finding the Ramsey number of $2\times$(complete graph of $2$ vertices) and $3\times$(the complete graph of two vertices).

I don't really understand if $2K_2$ is connected or not, and same with $3K_2$.

$2K_2$ is two disjoint copies of the complete graph $K_2$.
$2K_3$ is two disjoint copies of the complete graph $K_3$.

Comment: I would assume that the embedded "$K_2$" graphs would be separate (no shared vertices). Otherwise for example the first answer is that $K_3$ will contain 2 edges the same colour, which is not very interesting.

Comment: What do you mean by 2*(complete graph of 2 vertices) in the first place?  I know of $K_n$ being the complete graph on $n$ vertices.  I also know of $K_{m,n}$ the complete bipartite graph on $m+n$ vertices, and several products $K\times K, K\square K,$ and $K\boxtimes K$,  but I have never heard of a scalar times a graph.

Comment: Please review my edit for accuracy, and add explanation if you can to answer @JMoravitz points

Comment: Hey, sorry I added details to the question. It uses the notation in the book, but it means 2 disjoint complete graphs with 2 vertices and 3 disjoint complete graphs of 3 vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We prove that $R(2K_2,3K_2)=7$.

In a red-blue (edge-)colored $K_6$, let the red graph be $K_{1,5}$.
Since all edges are incident with the same vertex, the red graph does not contain $2K_2$.
The blue graph is $K_5+K_1$, which does not contain $3K_2$.
This proves that $R(2K_2,3K_2)>6$.

Now consider a red-blue colored $K_7$ that does not contain a red $2K_2$ or a blue $3K_2$.

If the red graph contains a cycle, it must be $C_3$, since every longer cycle contains $2K_2$.
But then the red graph cannot contain any other edge, since such edge $e$ is incident with
at most one of the vertices of the $C_3$ and then we find $2K_2$: the edge between
the other two vertices of the $C_3$ is independent of $e$. The blue graph ($K_7-C_3$)
clearly contains $3K_2$, contradiction.

So the red graph must be a tree, and because it cannot contain two independent edges,
this tree must be a star. The "worst" star on 7 vertices is $K_{1,6}$,
so the blue graph certainly contains $K_7-K_{1,6}$ as a subgraph,
which contains $C_7$, which contains $3K_2$. Contradiction.

This shows that $R(2K_2,3K_2)\leq7$ and we are done.